# Unity. How to render part of mesh.(pre-prepared vertex animation)

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, render, mesh, vertex

I have following task:
There is a mesh. Mesh contains several frames. At one time moment displayed one frame.
How can I render part of mesh?

For example in directX exists following method:
HRESULT IDirect3DDevice9::DrawPrimitive(
     D3DPRIMITIVETYPE PrimitiveType,
     UINT StartVertex,
     UINT PrimitiveCount
);
And I can set up displacement of start vertex and length.

Can I do something like this in unity?

Thx!